# Creating paragraphs in UITextview

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to split the text into paragraph in a UITextView?

Comment: Hello,
i have one uitextview and when i start writing it should be start like paragraph means start after some space.

is this possible?

Thank you,

Answer (score 4):

It's possible.

Example:

```
UITextView *testTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[testTextView setText:@"More\nBooks"];
```

It's displayed like 2 strings:

More

Books

Key for answer is: `\n` - end of line symbols.

Answer (score 0):

use NSMutableParagraphStyle in attributed string. 
and check other properties instead of paragraphSpacingBefore;

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
            paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 33.;

_textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string attributes:@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle}];
```